# get the most listed items in a array in php without removing duplicates (5)

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the top 5 most listed items out an `array` .
i have an `array` of states names, and i need the top 5 most listed states `array_unique()` doesn't work because i don't want to remove them.... i know i will need a `for-loop` some where im here....

php code:

```
<?
array(
'Florida', Illinois,New York, Texas, Florida, Alabama,California, Arizona,
'Florida', Illinois,New York, Texas, Florida, Alabama, Florida, Florida, texas.....
)
// now i want to get the top 5 listed within the array....
?>
```

Comment: Try [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/array_count_values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// trimming as there could be white space
// then count the frequency of each values. 
// see http://php.net/array_count_values for more.
$stat = array_count_values(array_map('trim', $data)); 

// sorting the array by *value* (a) keeping key associativity
// sorting order would be descending (r). 
// hence the sort function arsort()
arsort($stat);
// $stat contains your data
```

Related Links

1. [array_count_values](http://php.net/array_count_values)
2. [arsort](http://php.net/arsort)
3. [array_map](http://array_map)
4. [Sorting function attributes](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can do an [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) that generates an array with the value as key and the count as value, followed by an [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) with a compare function that compares the value.

Edit: as @Shiplu noted, arsort() can also be used not to have to define a comparer.

That'll give you an array sorted by frequency. Extracting the first (or last, depending on the comparer) 5 elements should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
$counted = array_count_values($data);
arsort($counted);
$top5 = array_slice($counted, 0, 5);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Florida] => 6
    [Texas] => 3
    [New York] => 2
    [Alabama] => 2
    [Illinois] => 2
)
```